# after installing ubuntu unable to open other drives on another hdd

Tags: system-installation

I installed Ubuntu 16.04.2 LTS, today
I had all my files saved on other HDD(with drives D,E,F,G) Now i cannot access any one of them. Please help

i have read few reports of other people facing same problems. But i have not kept windows as other boot option. Please find the details as i tried using one of the posted commands

```
Device         Start       End   Sectors   Size Type
/dev/sda1       2048   1050623   1048576   512M EFI System
/dev/sda2    1050624 454926335 453875712 216.4G Linux filesystem
/dev/sda3  454926336 488396799  33470464    16G Linux swap


Disk /dev/sdb: 1.8 TiB, 2000398934016 bytes, 3907029168 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0x5df7f82f

Device     Boot      Start        End    Sectors   Size Id Type
/dev/sdb1  *          2048  512002047  512000000 244.1G  7 HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
/dev/sdb2        512002048 1536002047 1024000000 488.3G  7 HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
/dev/sdb3       1536002048 2560002047 1024000000 488.3G  7 HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
/dev/sdb4       2560002048 3907026943 1347024896 642.3G  f W95 Ext'd (LBA)
/dev/sdb5       2560004096 3907026943 1347022848 642.3G  7 HPFS/NTFS/exFAT

arun@ArunAlterEgo:~$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 16.04.2 LTS
Release:    16.04
Codename:   xenial
```

Comment: If the disk is not showing up in the files, you can mount the disk with mount command. Later you can automount with fstab.

Comment: You still have 5 Windows partitions that apparently were not overwritten. Can you see these partitions in Nautilus? What happens if you click on them? Were the Windows partitions encrypted? Did you use Windows dynamic disks?

Answer (score 2):

You won't see drive letters such as C, D, E, F, in Linux.  You can see other drives and partitions as devices.

There are a few ways to bring up your other devices (drives).  The output you provided in your question is showing partitions where your files are saved.  Windows showed those devices as `D, E, F, G`.  Your output is showing them as:

```
/dev/sdb2
/dev/sdb3
/dev/sdb4
/dev/sdb5
```

### These are GUI methods for browsing your other drives

[image]

**View other drives via the file manager:**

Bring up your file manager by launching the application from your Ubuntu sidebar that looks like a file cabinet.  The application is **Nautilus**.  On the side bar of your Nautilus File Manager, you'll see devices near the bottom.  If those devices are in a recognizable format they will be listed.  Clicking on the filenames will bring up your other drive partitions.

Once you have found a drive or a folder that you will frequently visit, you can use Nautilus' bookmark option to easily access it quicker.

Click `Bookmark` while in the space you want to bookmark.  You can right click on the bookmark you create and give it a more friendly name.

**Viewing other drives via the Disk Manager**

YOu can bring up the Disk Manager by typing `disk` in the Ubuntu Dash search.  There you will be able to the physical drives by their names on the left panel of the window.  Then under the Volumes area, you can select the devices by their device names, `/dev/sdb2`, `/dev/sdb3`, etc.

**Viewing the devices via the Ubuntu Launcher**

A most obvious method (that is easily disabled and may be disabled inadvertently) is the Launcher.  It's revealed by bringing the mouse cursor all the way to the left of the screen.  (You can also use the keyboard shortcut <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd> to bring up the Ubuntu Launcher.)

New the bottom of the launcher you should see icons that resemble drives.  Clicking on those will also allow you to browse your other drives.